# Typesafe generics using TypeTag (with safe cast)

Tags: scala

I would like to implement parametric classes (like `List[T]`) that have the option to do a typesafe cast (e.g., `x.cast[List[U]]`).

By typesafe I mean that the cast may throw an exception if the type is incorrect at runtime, but it is guaranteed that if the cast succeeds, then the resulting value is of type `List[U]`. (For example, `asInstanceOf` does not do that. `List(1,2,3).asInstanceOf[List[String]]` will succeed, but return a `List` that does not contain `String`s.)

My approach is to tag all objects that should support casting with a `TypeTag`. Specifically, I would implement a trait `Typesafe` with a method `cast[U]` which expects an implicit `TypeTag` for type `U` and at runtime checks whether the types are subtypes. This is the code I have managed to come up with:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

trait Typesafe[+T <: Typesafe[T]] {
  val typeTag: TypeTag[_ <: T]

  def cast[U](implicit typeTag: TypeTag[U]) = {
    if (this.typeTag.tpe <:< typeTag.tpe)
      this.asInstanceOf[U]
    else
      throw new ClassCastException(s"Cannot cast ${this.typeTag} to ${typeTag}")
  }
}
```

The logic is: A class `T` that inherits `Typesafe[T]` will have to instantiate `typeTag` with a `TypeTag[T]`. And then the test in `cast[U]` can only succeed if `T` is indeed a subtype of `U` (otherwise, the implicit argument of `cast` does not exist).

We can implement this trait as follows (this is a simple wrapper class for Sets):

```
class TypesafeSet[T](val set : Set[T])
                    (implicit val typeTag:TypeTag[_<:TypesafeSet[T]])
  extends Typesafe[TypesafeSet[T]] {
}
```

Subtyping works, but unfortunately we need to specify the `extends Typesafe[...]` clause each time.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet
class TypesafeListSet[T](set: ListSet[T])
                        (implicit override val typeTag:TypeTag[_<:TypesafeListSet[T]])
  extends TypesafeSet[T](set) with Typesafe[TypesafeListSet[T]] {
}
```

**Question 1:** Can we improve on this pattern so that we don't have to repeat `extends Typesafe[...]` clause? (Currently, if we don't repeat it, `TypesafeListSet[T]` cannot be cast to `TypesafeListSet[T]`.)

However, in the following example, we have a problem:

```
class TypesafeList[T](val list : List[T])
                     (implicit val typeTag:TypeTag[_<:TypesafeList[T]])
  extends Typesafe[TypesafeList[T]] {
  val self = this
  def toSet : TypesafeSet[T] = new TypesafeListSet(ListSet(list : _*))
}
```

The method `toSet` does not compile, because the compiler cannot resolve the implicit `TypeTag[TypesafeListSet[T]]` for `new TypesafeListSet`. One would need to extract a `TypeTag[T]` from typeTag, and then reconstruct a `TypeTag[TypesafeListSet[T]]` from it. I don't know how this is possible.

**Question 2:** How to get the needed `TypeTag` in `toSet`? (One option would be to add an implicit argument of type `TypeTag[TypesafeListSet[T]]` to `toSet`, but that pushes the problem outwards, and leaks an implementation detail, namely that `toSet` uses a `ListSet`.)

Finally, the following code can be written, violating the type safety:

```
class TypesafeOption[T](val option : Option[T])
                       (implicit val typeTag:TypeTag[_<:TypesafeList[T]])
  extends Typesafe[TypesafeList[T]] {
}
```

Here, we have "accidentally" used `TypesafeList` in the argument of the `Typesafe` trait. This compiles fine, but it means that now `TypesafeOption` will have a `typeTag` for a `TypesafeList`! (And thus the check in `cast` will be incorrect, and wrong casts may happen.) I believe that such mixups can happen easily, and it would be good if they could be caught by the compiler. (To some extend, the type constraint `T <: Typesafe[T]` already avoid such mixups (following [this](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded)), but unfortunately not the one in `TypesafeOption`.)

**Question 3 ([answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426483/typesafe-generics-using-typetag-with-safe-cast/38438003#38438003)):**  Can we refine the definition of the trait `Typesafe` so that it is impossible to instantiate `Typesafe` in a way so that `cast` behaves incorrectly?

Finally, a few lines of code how these classes should be used:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeTag
object Test {
  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val list = new TypesafeList(List(1,2,3))
    val set = list.toSet
    val listSet : TypesafeListSet[Int] = set.cast[TypesafeListSet[Int]]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile. The compiler does not find the `TypeTag` for the call `new TypesafeList`. We need to add explicitly `(typeTag[TypesafeList[Int]])` in that line! (The reason is that `new TypesafeList` expects a `TypeTag[_ <: TypesafeList[Int]]`, and the compiler is not clever enough to see that he can just construct a `TypeTag[TypesafeList[Int]]`.)

**Question 4:** How can we define `TypesafeList` so that one does not need to explicitly give `TypeTag`s?

Finally, I have some questions concerning the overall example:

**Question 5:** There are (at least) two different `TypeTag` classes in the runtime, namely `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag` and `scala.reflect.api.TypeTags#TypeTag`. Which one is correct here?

**Question 6:** I am comparing the types contained in the `TypeTags` (i.e., `typeTag.tpe`). I ignore the mirrors. Should the mirrors be compared, too? (In other words, if two type tags have compatible types but different mirrors, will they be assignment-compatible?)

**Question 7:** (Possibly related to Question 6.) What happens if types of the same qualified name have been loaded by different classloaders? Will the code above be correct in this case? (I.e., it should not be possible to cast `test.Test` loaded from classloader 1 to `test.Test` loaded from classloader 2, as far as I understand.)

**Question 8 ([answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426483/typesafe-generics-using-typetag-with-safe-cast/38476893#38476893)):** Is `TypeTag` the right instrument here? Or should I rather tag the objects directly with `Type`s? (After all, I compare the types only in `cast`.) But as far as I can see (from various discussions), `TypeTag`s are presented as a solution to the problem of tagging classes for typesafety. Why? Or what are `TypeTag`s for?

**Question 9:** Any comments on the performance of this? Comparing two types at runtime (with `<:<`) sounds potentially expensive... Is there an alternative? (I thought of possibly constructing a map from `TypeTags`-pairs to `Boolean`s that remembers which types are assignment-compatible. However, would such the lookup be any faster? `TypeTag`s do not have unique ids for quick lookup as far as I know. (GHC uses "fingerprints" for this, I think.))

**Question 10:** Any other observations? Something that I do wrong? Is my conclusion that the `cast` is typesafe correct?

Comment: lt;dr. The first portion of your seems like something https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless does.

Comment: More specifically here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeable.scala

Comment: shapeless/Typeable has a similar goal, but there are two important differences:  

(a) It checks whether the cast is safe by recursively traversing the data structure (e.g., in list.cast(List[Int]), it will traverse all elements in the list and check whether they are integers.)  

(b) One needs to define a Typeable instance for any type that might be used as a type argument. (I.e., for `list.cast(List[Bla])`, we need that a Typeable[Bla] is in scope.) That makes it more difficult to use as a library (because the user will have to supply Typeable-instances for all his classes.

Comment: @DominiqueUnruh You have a lot of question, while they are all related, there is no way a single question can reasonably cover all of them. Could you split it up into several questions?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This solution is wrong. When using this solution, it is still possible to use `val typeTag = typeTag[Nothing]`, and then cast that class to any type.

**Answer to Question 3** (*Can we refine the definition of the trait `Typesafe` so that it is impossible to instantiate `Typesafe` in a way so that cast behaves incorrectly?*)

This can be done by specifying a "self-type" (see [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html)). In a trait, one can specify the type `T` that a class inheriting the class should have. This is done by writing `this:T =>` in the beginning of the trait's definition. In our particular case:

```
trait Typesafe[+T <: Typesafe[T]] {
  this : T =>
  val typeTag: TypeTag[_ <: T]

  def cast[U](implicit typeTag: TypeTag[U]) = {
    if (this.typeTag.tpe <:< typeTag.tpe)
      this.asInstanceOf[U]
    else
      throw new ClassCastException(s"Cannot cast ${this.typeTag} to ${typeTag}")
  }
}
```

Now any class that extends `Typesafe[T]` must be of type `T`. That is, one can only write `class X extends Typesafe[T]` if `T` is a supertype of `X`, and hence the type tag provided to `Typesafe` will be guaranteed to be for a supertype of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 8** *(Is TypeTag the right instrument here? Or should I rather tag the objects directly with Types?)*:

One reason is that a `TypeTag` has a type parameter that represents the type that is tagged. That is, `TypeTag[T]` statically enforces that we have a `TypeTag` for `T`. If we would use `Type` instead, it would not be enforced that the value `Typesafe.typeTag` is a tag of the right type.

Example:

```
trait Typesafe[+T <: Typesafe[T]] {
  val typ: Type
  [...]
}
```

Now one could write:

```
class TypesafeSet[T](val set : Set[T])
  extends Typesafe[TypesafeSet[T]] {
  val typ = typeOf[String] // !!!
}
```

There seems to be no way to avoid this without a `TypeTag`.

(This does not explain, however, why the `TypeTag` needs to have a mirror in it in addition to the type.)